# R plot color vector

Tags: r, colors, plot

I am having problems matching the correct color vector which I use in 'plot' function and the color vector in a subset of my data which I use to add a legend to my data. I was windering if you have any suggestions? I have been trying to specify an order for the colorvector, but when I turn it into factor the levels of the factors are re-ordered automatically.

This is my sample data:

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
class<- c(NA,NA,'S','S','T','V','G','S')
x<- c(5,3,2,7,6,4,8,3)
y<- c(8,4,1,8,4,8,3,1)
df<- data.frame(ID,class,x,y)
df$choose <- c('FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE','TRUE','TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE')
df$colorvector <- 'gray'
split(df$colorvector, df$class)<- c('black', 'red', 'blue', 'orange')

plot(df$x,df$y,col=df$colorvector)
text(df$x[df$choose==TRUE], df$y[df$choose==TRUE], labels=df$ID[df$choose==TRUE], cex=0.8,   pos=2, font=1)
legend("topright", inset=.05, title="IDs with same class",
legend=sort(levels(df$class[df$choose==TRUE])), fill=levels(as.factor(df$colorvector[df$choose==TRUE])), horiz=TRUE)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making the mistake of assuming that when you make colorvector into a factor that its levels sort in the same was as class.  One solution would be to just assign your colours in alphabetical order.  A better way might be to get your legend information from this data...

```
> unique(df[,c('class','choose','colorvector')])
  class choose colorvector
1  <NA>  FALSE        gray
3     S   TRUE         red
5     T   TRUE        blue
6     V   TRUE      orange
7     G   TRUE       black
```

Now everything will be in the right order.

Comment: Thank you John, I get it now.. I think I'll try with ggplot2 though because I don't want to create another df (my data is huge)..

Comment: The df is just unique items.  It will be relatively very small.  If it isn't you couldn't make a reasonable legend anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you!

Thanks you for asking a question that reminded me of why I started using `ggplot2`. Lots of folks around here joke about how much `ggplot2` is pushed as the answer to plotting questions, and frankly we do over do it a tad.

But man, I can't remember the last time I had to fuss with a legend like this. Try:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = ID,colour = class)) + 
    scale_colour_brewer(pal = 'Set1')
```

[image]

Obviously, you can set your own color palette, this was just one I liked.

Comment: Hi Joran…thank you. I had to install ggplot2 (ggplot would not install in my version of R), and I think I almost got it but I am having some issues with the text labelling still…The geom_text is not working, can you help me figure out why please? This is the code now: library('ggplot2')  qplot(data=df, x=df$x,y=df$y, colour=df$class)
  geom_text(data=df$ID[df$choose==TRUE])

Comment: @user971102 It will be easier to help you if you stop by the [R chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r) room, rather than going back and forth in the comments.